# What is the language of this deterministic finite automata?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, finite-automata, deterministic

Given:

[image]

I have no idea what the accepted language is.

From looking at it you can get several end results:

```
1.) bb
2.) ab(a,b)
3.) bbab(a, b)
4.) bbaaa
```

Comment: Possible duplicate from math.stackexchange http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739863/finding-the-language-of-a-finite-automaton

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### How to write regular expression for a DFA

In any automata, the purpose of state is like memory element. A state stores some information in automate like ON-OFF fan switch.
A Deterministic-Finite-Automata(DFA)  called *finite* automata because *finite amount of memory* present in the form of states. For any Regular Language(RL) a DFA is always possible.

Let's see what information stored in the DFA (refer my colorful figure).
(*note: In my explanation any number means zero or more times and `Λ` is null symbol*)

---

**State-1:** is START state and information stored in it is **even number of** `a` **has been come. And ZERO** `b`.
Regular Expression(RE) for this state is **=** `(aa)*`.

**State-4:** Odd number of **`a`** has been come. And ZERO **`b`**.
Regular Expression for this state is **=** `(aa)*a`.

> [image: FIGURE:]

**Figure:**  a **BLUE** states = **EVEN** number of **`a`**,  and  **RED** states = **ODD** number of **`a`** has been come.

> **NOTICE:** Once first *b* has been  come, move can't back to state-1 and state-4.

**State-5:** comes after `Yellow b`. `Yellow b` **means** `b after odd numbers of a`.
Once you gets **`b`** after odd numbers of **`a`**(at state-5) every thing is acceptable because there is self a loop for (b,a) at state-5.

You can write for state-5 : Yellow-b followed-by any string of a, b that is **=** `Yellow-b`  `(a + b)*`

**State-6:** Just to differentiate whether odd **`a`** or even.

**State-2:** comes after even **`a`** then **`b`** then any number of **`b`**. **=** `(aa)*` `bb*`

**State-3:** comes after state-2 then first `a` then there is a loop via state-6. 
We can write for state-3 comes **=** `state-2` `a` `(aa)*`  **=**  `(aa)*bb*` `a` `(aa)*`

Because in our DFA, we have three final states so language accepted by DFA is union (+ in RE) of three RL (or three RE).
So the language accepted by the DFA is corresponding to three accepting **states-2,3,5**, And we can write like:

```
 State-2 +  state-3           + state-5
```

`(aa)*bb*`  + `(aa)*bb*` `a` `(aa)*` + `Yellow-b` `(a + b)*`

I forgot to explain `how Yellow-b comes?`
ANSWER: `Yellow-b` is a `b` after state-4 or state-3. And we can write like:

`Yellow-b` **=** `( state-4 + state-3 )` `b` **=**  ( `(aa)*a` + `(aa)*bb*` `a` `(aa)*` ) `b`

[**ANSWER**]
`(aa)*bb*`  + `(aa)*bb*` `a` `(aa)*` + ( `(aa)*a` + `(aa)*bb*` `a` `(aa)*` ) `b` `(a + b)*`

---

**English Description of Language**: DFA accepts union of three languages

- EVEN NUMBERs OF **`a`**'s, FOLLOWED BY ONE OR MORE **`b`**'s,
- EVEN NUMBERs OF **`a`**'s, FOLLOWED BY ONE OR MORE **`b`**'s, FOLLOWED BY ODD NUMBERs OF **`a`**'s.
- A PREFIX STRING OF **`a`** AND **`b`** WITH ODD NUMBER OF **`a`**'s, FOLLOWED BY **`b`**, FOLLOWED BY ANY STRING OF **`a`** AND **`b`** AND **`Λ`**.

English Description is complex but this the only way to describe the language. You can improve it by first convert given DFA into minimized DFA then write RE and description.

---

Also, there is a Derivative Method to find RE from a given Transition Graph using [Arden's Theorem](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=fodwUrSC8e0C&pg=SA3-PA7&lpg=SA3-PA7&dq=arden%27s%20theorem%20for%20regular%20language&source=bl&ots=QTuxWbiATB&sig=Rf32daVHvstUV5JyExianv6A4Pw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sSkZUb-9E8iUrgejlIEw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=arden%27s%20theorem%20for%20regular%20language&f=false). I have explained here [how to write a regular expression for a DFA using Arden's theorem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420332/need-regular-expression-for-finite-automata/17434694#17434694). The transition graph must first be converted into a standard form without the null-move and single start state. But I prefer to learn Theory of computation by analysis instead of using the Mathematical derivation approach.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this question isn't relevant anymore :) and it's probably better to guide you through it then just stating the answer, but I think I got a basic expression that covers it (it's probably minimizable), so i'll just write it down for future searchers

```
(aa)*b(b)* // for stoping at 2
U
(aa)*b(b)*a(aa)* // for stoping at 3
U
(aa)*b(b)*a(aa)*b((a)*(b)*)* // for stoping at 5 via 3
U
a(aa)*b((a)*(b)*)* // for stoping at 5 via 4
```

Answer (score 1):

The examples (1 - 4) that you give there are **not** the *language* accepted by the DFA. They are merely strings that **belong to the language** that the DFA accepts. Therefore, they all fall in the same language.

If you want to figure out the *regular expression* that defines that DFA, you will need to do something called *k-path induction*, and you can read up on it [here](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc/spr10/slides/re1.pdf).

Comment: ok, I'm not completely sure but  I came up with : it must contain a {b} and have an odd number of {a}.

Comment: Kleene's theorem gives algorithms for producing an NFA-Lambda or a RE given a RE or a FA, respectively.

Comment: This answer should have more upvotes IMO. The link you provide gives a great explanation (by Jeff Ullmann!).