# How to solve δ(A,01) for this DFA?

Tags: finite-automata, regular-language, automata, dfa

[image]
Consider the DFA :

**What will be δ(A,01) equal to ?**
options:

```
A) {D}    
B) {C,D}      
C) {B,C,D}       
D) {A,B,C,D}
```

The correct answer is option B) but I don't get how. Please some one explain me the steps to solve it and also in general how do we solve sit for any DFA and any transition?

Thanks.

Comment: 11 views but no replies :( Is this such a difficult concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**B) Option is not Correct answer!** for this transition graph.

In Transition Graph(TG) symbol `ε` means **NULL-move** (`ε-move`). There is two NULL-moves in TG.

```
One:       (A) --- `ε` ---->(B)  
Second:    (A) --- `ε` ---->(C)
```

A `ε-move` means without consume any symbol you can change state. In your diagram from `A to B`, or `A to C`.

> What will be δ(A,01) equal to ?

Question asked  "what is path from state `A` if input is `01`". (as I understand because there is only one final state)

`01` can be processed in either of two ways.

> - (A) -- ε --->(B) -- 0 --> (B) -- 1 --> (D)
> - (A) -- ε --->(C) -- 0 --> (B) -- 1 --> (D)

Also, there is no other way to process string `01` even if you don't wants to reach final state.

[**ANSWER**]
So there is misprinting in question (or either you did).

You can learn how to remove NULL-move from transition graph. Also [HOW TO WRITE REGULAR EXPRESSION FOR A DFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550711/what-is-the-language-of-this-deterministic-finite-automata/13965717#13965717)

If you remove null-moves from TG you will get three ways to accept `01`.

[image: TG]

**EQUIVALENT TRANSITION GRAPH WITHOUT NULL-MOVE**

Note there is three start-states in Graph.

Three ways:

```
{ABD}  
{CBD}  
{BBD}
```

In all option `state-(B)` has to be come.

Also, you have written `Consider the DFA :` is wrong. The TG is not deterministic because there is there is non-deterministic move δ(A,ε) and next states are either B or C.

Comment: Thanks a lot Grijesh for your efforts to answer this :)

Comment: @BriteRoy Welcome Brite Roy :)