# What will be the DFA for the regular expression 0(0+1)*0+1(0+1)*1?

Tags: theory, regular-language, automata, dfa, computation-theory

This is the DFA i have drawn-

[image: MyDFA]

Is it correct?
I am confused because `q4` state has `2` different transitions for same input symbol which violates the rule of `DFA`, but I can't think of any other solution.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550711/what-is-the-language-of-this-deterministic-finite-automata/13965717#13965717) .

Comment: chirs view my updated answer I corrected DFA

Comment: Determinicy refers to the fact that it is not allowed to have two outgoing transitions with the same label from the same state. It does **not** refer to incomming transitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DFA is not correct.
 <sub>your DFA is completely wrong so I don't comment</sub>

DFA for RE:

```
0(1 + 0)*0 + 1(1 + 0)*1
```

**Language Description**: if string start with `0` it should end with `0` or if string start with `1` it should end with `1`. hence two final states (state-5, state-4).

state-4 : accepts  `1(1 + 0)*1`
state-5 : accepts  `0(1 + 0)*0`
state-1 : start state.

**DFA**:

[image: DFA]

**EDIT** :

### + Operator in Regular Expression

`(0 + 1)* = (1 + 0)*` that is any string consist of `1`s and `0`s, including Null string `^`.

Here `+` means Union if it appear between two RE: and `A U B = B U A`  (similarly)=> `(0 + 1) = (0 + 1)` .

<sub>meaning of plus `+` depends on syntax it appears in:  If expression is a<sup>+</sup> (`+` is superscripted) this means one of more `a`s, and If `a+b` then `+` means Union operation either `a` or `b`.</sub>

`a+ : { a, aa, aaa, aaa.....}` that is any number of `a` string in language with `length > 1`.

Comment: I believe it is  0(0+1)*0+1(0+1)*1 instead of  0(1 + 0)*0 + 1(1 + 0)*1

Comment: @HélioSantos Is there any difference?

Comment: yes, its a regular expression, not a math expression.

(0+1) => one or more zeroes followed by a one
(1+0) => one or more one followed by a zero

Comment: @HélioSantos Yes it is a regular expression.
I think (0+1)* means any number of zeroes and ones, same as (1+0)* .
From your point, my regular expression doesnot accept 0010, but it does.

Comment: @Chris that would be 
[01]* any number of zeroes OR ones
(01|10)* any number of the combination 01 OR 10.
Try here(http://rubular.com/).
Which regex implementation are you using?

Comment: @HélioSantos `(0 + 1)*` means any string consist of `0`s and `1`s including `^` and `(O+1)* = (1+0)*`. Actually `+` means Union and `A U B` = `B U A`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `+` is a quantifier. The element before `+` should appear one or more times (http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). Are we talking about the same thing - regex??

Comment: @HélioSantos meaning of plus depends on syntax it appears if expression is `a+` this means one of more `a`s and if `a+b` then `+` means Union operation either `a` or `b`.

Comment: @HélioSantos [**+ in Regular Expression**](http://www.jflap.org/tutorial/regular/index.html)

Comment: @HélioSantos Welcome your! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with 0 first

```
0(1 + 0)*0 + 1(1 + 0)*1
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code (or formula) is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.