# Why L={wxw^R| w, x belongs to {a,b}^+ } is a regular language

Tags: automation, regular-language, dfa, nfa, pumping-lemma

Using pumping lemma, we can easily prove that the language `L1 = {WcW^R|W ∈ {a,b}*}` is **not a regular language**. (the alphabet is {a,b,c}; W^R represents the reverse string W)

However, If we replace character `c` with `"x"(x ∈ {a,b}+)`, say, `L2 = {WxW^R| x, W ∈ {a,b}^+}`, then L2 **is a regular language**.

Could you give me some ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you want? I suggest you revise your question "Could you give me some ideas?" to something more concise and constructive.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> If we replace character c with x where (x ∈ {a,b}<sup>+</sup>), say, L2 = {WXW<sup>R</sup>| x, W ∈ {a,b}<sup>+</sup>}, then L2 is a regular language.

Yes, `L2` is Regular Language :).

<sub>You can write regular expression for `L2` too.</sub>

Language L2 = {WXW<sup>R</sup>| x, W ∈ {a,b}<sup>+</sup>}  means:

- string should start any string consist of `a` and `b` that is `W` and end with reverse string W<sup>R</sup>.
- *notice:* because W and W<sup>R</sup> are reverse of each other so string start and end with same symbol *(that can be either `a` or `b`)*
- And contain *any string* of `a` and `b` in middle that is `X`. (because of `+`, length of `X` becomes greater than one `|X| >= 1`)

Example of this kind of strings can be following:

aabababa, as follows:

```
   a    ababab    a  
  --   --------   --
   w     X        W^R
```

or it can be also:

babababb, as follows:

```
   b    ababab    b
  --   --------   --
   w     X        W^R
```

See length of `W` is not a constraint in language definition.

so any string WXW<sup>R</sup> can be assume equals to `a(a + b)`<sup>+</sup>`a` or `b(a + b)`<sup>+</sup>`b`

```
    a    (a + b)+   a
   ---   --------  ---
    W      X       W^R
```

or

```
    b    (a + b)+   b
   ---   --------  ---
    W      X       W^R
```

And Regular Expression for this language is: `a(a + b)`<sup>+</sup>`a` `+` `b(a + b)`<sup>+</sup>`b`

<sub>Don't mix `WXW`<sup>R</sup> with `WCW`<sup>R</sup>, its `X` with `+` that makes language regular. Think by including `X` that is `(a + b)*` we can have **finite choice** for `W` that is `a` and `b` (finite is regular).</sub>

Language `WXW`<sup>R</sup> can be say: if start with `a` ends with `a` and if start with `b` end with `b`. so correspondingly we need two final states.

- Q6 if `W` is `a`
- Q5 if `W` is `b`

ITs DFA is as given below.

[image: DFA]

Comment: To draw it DFA see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122755/what-will-be-the-dfa-for-the-regular-expression-00101011?answertab=votes#tab-top) bit similar

Comment: Does it mean we can not just pick one of x strings? As the example you mention above, If we just select x = “ababab” and w = a^n, then we get wxw^R = (a^n)ababab(a^n). However, if we use pumping lemma, it seems that this example fails. That's the part I am confused. When should we choose an appropriate couterexample with pumping lemma. For the example wxw^R, we can not fix x, say x = specific strings, if we fix it, we fail to pass pumping lemma.

Comment: No `W` is just single symbol either `a` or `b`

Comment: I know why I am confused. We still can apply pumping lemma in to the second language, say, xy^(2)z = a^(n+|y|) baaba^(n) (we randomly select x=baab). We note that xy^(2)z also = a^(n) a^(|y|)baab a^(n). This is still in the language L, no contradiction. Previous, I mistake this as a contradiction. It is nothing to do with whether we fix x or not. No matter what strings we select from x, we still can get strings that belong to language L. Thanks @Grijesh :-)

Comment: @Patrick87 yes, sorry I forgot to add two loop. Thanks Patrick!

Answer (score 2):

Any string in the language with |W| > 1 can be interpreted as a string in the language where |W| = 1. Thus, a string is in the language if it begins and ends with the same symbol. There are two symbols: a and b. So that language is equivalent to the language `a(a+b)(a+b)*a + b(a+b)(a+b)*b`. To prove this, you should formalize the argument that "if y is in WxW, then y is in a(a+b)(a+b)*a + b(a+b)(a+b)*b; and if y is in a(a+b)(a+b)*a + b(a+b)(a+b)*b, then y is in WxW".

It doesn't work in the other case since c is a fixed symbol, and can't include all but the characters on the ends. As soon as you bound the length of "x" in your example, the language becomes non-regular.

Comment: My original wrong method is like --> We a specific "x", say x = abab, then when we applying pumping lemma, it turns out a contradiction. BUT this is a wrong method. We cannot specify any string of "x" and use pumping lemma to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

The question says W ∈ {a,b}^+ , so a^n(a+b)a^n should be in the language L2. Now there is no such DFA that will accept the string a^n(a+b)a^n because, after accepting n number of a and (a+b)^+, there is no way for the dfa to remember exactly how many a it accepted in the begining, so L2 should not be regular.........But every where i search for this answer it says it is regular.....this bugs me