# Is this a regular language? If so, what is it's regular expression?

Tags: regex, computer-science, regular-language

```
B = {1^k y | k >= 1, y in {0, 1}* and y contains at least k 1's }
```

Is this language regular?  If so, how do you prove it, and how would you represent it with a regular expression in Python?

This is for class work, so if you could explain the reasons and processes behind your answer, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: We haven't studied context-free languages yet - how can you tell that?

Comment: It's not regular, because you can't store an arbitrary size `k` in a finite number of states.  For a formal proof use the pumping lemma.

Comment: @starblue - Isn't the Pumping Lemma necessary but not sufficient?

Comment: @camdroid: Proof by contradiction. If the necessary condition is not met, then it is not regular expression.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Proof by contradiction using Pumping Lemma will prove that a language is irregular, but I want to prove that it is regular, and the converse of the Pumping Lemma doesn't hold.

Comment: @nhahtdh: It is regular - I know what the answer is, I'm trying to understand how to arrive at it.

Comment: Misread the question (didn't read the "at least"). If it is equal then most probably not regular.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong.  The trick is that there is no unambiguous boundary between the two parts, so you can move ones into the y part.

Comment: Can you explain the notation? Obviously y is a binary number, what is 1^k? ::: My University days are long ago, but by definiton if you can represent the set by a regex it is regular (hence the name 'regular' in regular expression)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The language you have is equivalent to this language:

```
B' = {1 y | y in {0, 1}* and y contains at least one 1}
```

You can prove that B' is subset of B, since the condition in B' is the same as B, but with k set to 1.

Proving B is subset of B' involves proving that all words in B where k >= 1 also belongs to B', which is easy, since we can take away the first 1 in all words in B and set `y` to be the rest of the string, then `y` will always contain at least one 1.

Therefore, we can conclude that `B = B'`.

---

So our job is simplified to ensuring the first character is 1 and there is at least 1 `1` in the rest of the string.

The regular expression (the CS notation) will be:

```
10*1(0 + 1)*
```

In the notation used by common regex engines:

```
10*1[01]*
```

The DFA:

[image: DFA]

Here `q2` is a final state.

**"At least"** is the key to solving this question. If the word becomes "equal", then the story will be different.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: What's your counter-example?

Comment: @nhahtdh update your answer so that I can vote-up. you are correct one more [related question is here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521300/why-l-wxwr-w-x-belongs-to-a-b-is-a-regular-language)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Update **what**?

Comment: @nhahtdh I by mistake voted you down, but I can't revert till you update you answer :(