# CFG and its reverse

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory

I'm trying to wrap my head around CGS's. Let `E^*` be 'epsilon star', `e` be the empty string, and `ww^r` be w next to the reverse of w.

I know that building up a CFG to accept `E^*` is a simple `S -> 0S | 1S | e`.

A CGG that accepts `{ww^r} such that w in E^*` is a simple `S –> 0S0 | 1S1 | e`.

Does that mean a CFG accepting `{wxw^r} such that w, x in E^*` is a sort of 'composition' of these two resulting in `S –> 0S0 | 1S1 | e | B where B –> 0B | 1B | e`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why L={wxw^R| w, x belongs to {a,b}^+ } is a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521300/why-l-wxwr-w-x-belongs-to-a-b-is-a-regular-language)

Comment: this Title for you question is not correct: CFG and its reverse

Comment: @clever Although You have accepted but I made some changes in answer and added one more link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your grammar is correct!

CFG to `{wxw^r} such that w, x in E^*` is `S –> 0S0 | 1S1 | e | B where B –> 0B | 1B | e` is correct grammar.

But important is Language `{wxw^r} such that w, x in E^*` is [Regular Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) so it also possible to write [**Left-Linear and Right-Linear Grammars**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816439/left-linear-and-right-linear-grammars?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

A **Right-Liner equivalent Grammar** for this language is:

```
S --> 0B | 1A | ^
B --> 0B | 1B | 0
A --> 0A | 1A | 1
```

And **Left Liner** equivalent is:

```
S --> B0 | A1 | ^
B --> B0 | B1 | 0
A --> A0 | A1 | 1
```

Its regular expression is:

> 0(0 + 1)*0 + 1(0 + 1)*1 + ^

A similar language I [described here in my answer with DFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521300/why-l-wxwr-w-x-belongs-to-a-b-is-a-regular-language/14534863#14534863).

*note:* language structure is same but symbol are not, also there is `^` null string is not possible. Also there is `+` on `( 0 + 1)` here is `*`

Its DFA

[image: DFA]

Additionally, I would also encourage you to view DFA for `0(1 + 0)*0 + 1(1 + 0)*1` . Notice a small change of `^` in RE but DFAs are quite different.

Comment: Umm, `wxw^r` - where `w^r` is the reverse of `w` - is not regular. You can prove this easily using the Myhill-Nerode theorem or the pumping lemma for regular languages.

Comment: Oh wait a sec, you're right. :) Forgot about this one. Looking at the linked question, it looks like I got the right answer there. Oops.