# Will L={xww^R| w, x belongs to {0,1}^+ } is a regular language or not

Tags: automation, regular-language

I have already seen that wxw^r is regular as explained in this post 
[Why L={wxw^R| w, x belongs to {a,b}^+ } is a regular language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521300/why-l-wxwr-w-x-belongs-to-a-b-is-a-regular-language)

if i apply the same logic here that w will eat up everything except the last two 
symbols which can be either 0 or 1

ex : 
     w=101

```
 x=1010

 w^r=101

 then string is 1010101101

now x will be 10101011
so we can construct a regular expression (0+1)*(0+1)(0+1)

so it should be regular
is my explanation correct or the language will not be regular because where
```

i seen the question it was written that the language is not regular with no 
explanation

Answer (score 4):

Consider `{W X W^r | W,X belongs to (0,1)^+}`

Then suppose

```
W= 101
W^r = 101
X=11
```

then the String will be

```
101 11 101
W   X  W^r
```

then if `x` consumes all others except the last and first character,
then string will look like

```
  1  011110  1
  W    X     W^r
```

then also the String follows the pattern `W X W^r`, note that.

But in your example  `X W W^r`
suppose  `x=11  w=101  w^r=101`
then the string will be

```
11 101 101
X   W   W^r
```

if now `X` consume all the character except the last two chars,
then string will look like

```
111011  0  1
   X    W  W^r
```

note that `W` & `W^r` aren't the same, or in some cases,
they may be the same, but according to language `X W W^r`,
the last two symbols or last two strings of equal length
should be reversal, but they aren't,
so the language is not regular.