# Regular Languages

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory

I have come across many forums where they state that the language represented by

> L={WW<sup>R</sup>|W<sup>R</sup> is the reverse of W and W belongs to (0,1)<sup>*</sup>}

is NOT REGULAR. And it has been proved by pumping lemma as well.

BUT I am able to write a REGULAR EXPRESSION FOR THIS, where I use the same logic as given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521300/why-l-wxwr-w-x-belongs-to-a-b-is-a-regular-language) link.

CHECK THIS:

> (0+1) <sup>*</sup> 11 (0+1) <sup>*</sup> + (0+1) <sup>*</sup> 00 (0+1) <sup>*</sup>

Is there any flaw in logic? Or something that I maybe missing.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(0+1) * 11 (0+1) * + (0+1) * 00 (0+1) * + (0+1) *           initial
= (0+1) * 11 (0+1) * + ((0+1) * 00 (0+1) * + (0+1) *)       union is associative
= (0+1) * 11 (0+1) * + (0+1) *                              L u U = U (U is universe)
= (0+1) *                                                   L u U = U (U is universe)
```

Your regular expression, which contains a union with `(0+1)*`, is the language which contains all strings of `0`s and `1`s and contains the target language as a proper subset. Your language contains, among other strings not in the target language, the string `01100`.

Note that I am taking `+` to mean union, juxtaposition to mean concatenation, and `*` to mean Kleene closure.