# What's the regex corresponding to this DFA?

Tags: regex, regular-language, fsm, dfa

Here is a DFA from a research project. We created the DFA manually. We are interested in What is Regular Expression  that is corresponding to DFA . Certainly, there could be multiple 
Regular Expressions corresponding to it; we prefer a simpler one.

[image]

Comment: wait what is label for self loop on B ,E

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the labels in you DFA on self loop at B and E. But because you say *for given DFA* then only choice for labels is `0` on both loop.

The correct Regular Expression for your DFA is:

```
(00* 10*1)* (1(0 + 10)* 1 1) ( 0 + 1 (00* 10*1)* 1  ( 0 + 10)* 1 1)*
```

A brief explanation:

1. You have only one final  state that is `D`. So string can be acceptable if it ends on `D`. 
   do you notice incoming edge on `D` is labeled `1` and `D` has a self loop labeled `0`.
2. Start state is `A` so string can be start with `0` or with `1`. Actually there is two loops on A. One starts with `0`  and travels through upper graph.
   RE for upper loop is:  `00* 10*1`

   To understand this:

   ```
     0     0*           1      0*            1  

    A-E   loop on E     E-F    loop on F     F-A
   ```
3. To go from `A` to `D` in lower graph. RE is `1 (0 + 10)* 1 1`
   To understand this:

   ```
    1        (0 + 10)*    1     1
    A - B    loop on B    B-C   C-D
   ```
4. The complete RE for DFA is: (*answer*)

   ```
   (00* 10*1)* (1(0 + 10)* 1 1) ( 0 + 1 (00* 10*1)* 1  ( 0 + 10)* 1 1)*
   ```

   To understand this:

   ```
   (00* 10*1)*  (1(0 + 10)* 1 1) ( 0 + 1 (00* 10*1)* 1 ( 0 + 10)* 1 1)*

   ^             ^                                                    ^   
   upper loop    A to D           loop on D              * for loop on D    


                         ( 0 +  1    (00* 10*1)* 1    (0 + 10)*   1  1  )*
                           ^    D-A   A-A        A-B  loop on B, B-c c-D       
                        self loop on D
   ```

**Edit**  as  @RedBaron commented does this Regular expression generate string `01110100110` :

well fist check is it accepted by DFA or not:

> A--0--> E--1---> F--1---> A---1---> B--0---> B---1--->C---0---
>    ->B---0---> B--1-->C---1---> D---0--->D‌​

Yes string is accepted by DFA.

How to generate from RE I given in answer, below I have aligned the RE and string.

```
(00* 10*1)*    (1(0 + 10)* 1 1) ( 0 + 1 (00* 10*1)* 1 ( 0 + 10)* 1 1)*

 0^  1^ 1      1  0100     1  1   0
```

Only the difficulty you may have to understand: how `(0 + 10)*` generates `0100`? for this check below:

`(0 + 10)*` be repeat for three times:

```
(0 + 10)(0 + 10)(0 + 10)
 0           10  0
```

Comment: `00*` at the beginning can be changed to `0+` and for loop on B I think (0+10)* is wrong because `000` `010` `10` all create the loop

Comment: @RedBaron yes `00*` can be written as `0+` i don't use it because of superscript notion...Second, B has two loops one self loop `0*` and other `10` loop via `C` so combined both in (0 + 10)* read point 3

Comment: Shouldn't that combine to `(0*(10)*)*`?

Comment: How can `(0+10)*` generate `0100` <scratches head>

Comment: @RedBaron yes `(0 + 10)* == (0*(10)*)* == (0* + (10)*)*`

Comment: @RedBaron Ok We knows, `+` means union. `( A + B)` means either `A` or `B`. similarly `(0 + 10)` means either `0` or `10`. because `*` means any numbers of time. so `(0 + 10)*` means any numbers of time 0 or `10`.

Comment: Maybe you'd want to run your regexp and the test strings through a regexp engine to cross-check

Comment: In regexp `+` means 1 or more occurences and **not** union, I presume

Comment: @RedBaron actually + means both its mean dependences on syntax it appears in read this [+ Operator in Regular Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122755/what-will-be-the-dfa-for-the-regular-expression-00101011?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Ahh.... different planes of discussions. I was wholly thinking about regular expressions while you had language in mind. Anyways my answer was purely from a regexp point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Jack, basically there can be two regex for this DFA.
first can be AB*CD*A,
second can be AE*F*

Answer (score 0):

`10*110*` is for transition from A-B-C-D without the loop in c-B

`1(0*(10)*)*110*` I think also covers the loop between C and B

`0+10*1` is the loop from A-E-F. So you can prefix it to both the expressions

You get `(0+10*1)*10*110*` without the loop and `(0+10*1)*1(0*(10)*)*110*` with it

The final expression is thus

```
(0+10*1)*1(0*(10)*)*110*
```

for transitioning from A to D

Finally on reaching the state D you could get a `1`, reach `A` and repeat the whole thing over again

```
((0+10*1)*1(0*(10)*)*110*)(1((0+10*1)*1(0*(10)*)*110*))*
```

[See it in action](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%280%2b10%2a1%29%2a1%280%2a%2810%29%2a%29%2a110%2a%29%281%28%280%2b10%2a1%29%2a1%280%2a%2810%29%2a%29%2a110%2a%29%29%2a%24&input=01110100110%0A111%0A1110%0A01011000110%0A1001001) for some valid and invalid strings for this DFA

**Clarification** - This regexp is based on regular expressions as accepted by PCRE. So `+` means 1 or more occurences of a string and `*` means 0 or more occurences, while `|` means `OR`

**EDIT** The `(0*(10)*)*` can be written better as `(0|(10))*` (Thanks to @grijesh-chauhan for pointing me in that direction). So the RE (PCRE based) would be

```
((0+10*1)*1(0|(10))*110*)(1((0+10*1)*1(0|(10))*110*))*
```

Comment: Slight typo there...fixed it

Comment: I also assume that E and B self transitions occur at 0 (The digit is missing in the figure)

Comment: your basic regular expression is correct, but review again. Can you find why your expression is wrong? it good question....  (*i am not downvoter*)

Comment: No I can't. BTW your Regexp does not accept 01110100110 which is a vlid string for this DFA

Comment: @RedBaron check again my answer as well as you answer. also check both question you asked in comment. I commented to you post because you were just near to answer. And my RE process you string `A --0--E--1---F--1---A---1---B--0---B---1--C---0---B---0---B--1--C---1---D---0---D`

Comment: That is for the DFA and is evindent from the figure. But does your _regexp_ allow such a string?

Comment: @grijesh-chauhan Check your regexp on [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=^%2800*10*1%29*%281%280%2B10%29*11%29%280%2B1%2800*10*1%29*1%280%2B10%29*11%29*%24&input=01110100110%0A111%0A1110%0A01011000110%0A1001001)

Comment: @RedBaron read my updated answer, don't try with tool the are not regular language renovators indeed!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27203/discussion-between-redbaron-and-grijesh-chauhan)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you need to use is described [here](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=265064). I strongly recommend reading Michael Sipser's [Introduction to the Theory of Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/113318779X) if you're more interested in the topic.

For your particular DFA, following the algorithm you get this regex:

```
[(010*1)*1(10*)110*1]*(010*1)*1(10)*110*
```

Comment: your regex is very close to the DFA. By drawing your regex to DFA, the transition from D to A is missing.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Obviously this is much better done by computer since it's easy to make mistakes.