# Show that the following set over {a,b} is regular

Tags: regular-language, dfa, nfa, alphabet

Given the alphabet `{a, b}` we define `Na(w)` as the number of occurrences of `a` in the word `w` and similarly for `Nb(w)`. Show that the following set over `{a, b}` is regular.

> `A = {xy | Na(x) = Nb(y)}`

I'm having a hard time figuring out where to start solving this problem. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CS theory (try http://cs.stackexchange.com instead...)


Comment: @user2804857 Correct tags are important.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is regular language!

Any string consists if `a` and `b` belongs the language `A = {xy | Na(x) = Nb(y)}`.

**Example:**
Suppose string is: `w = aaaab` we can divide this string into prefix `x` and suffix `y`

```
  w =   a     aaab
       ---   -----
        x      y
```

Number of `a` in `x`   is one, and  number of `b` in in `y` is also one.

Similarly as string like: `abaabaa` can be broken as `x = ab` (N<sub>a</sub>(x) = 1) and `y = aabaa` (N<sub>b</sub>(y) = 1).

Or `w = bbbabbba` as `x = bbbabb` (N<sub>a</sub>(x) = 1) and `y = ba` (N<sub>b</sub>(y) = 1)

Or `w = baabaab` as x = `baa`  and `y = baab` with (N<sub>a</sub>(x) = 2) and (N<sub>b</sub>(y) = 2).

So you can always break a string consist of `a` and `b` into prefix `x` and suffix `y` such that N<sub>a</sub>(x) = (N<sub>b</sub>(y).

**Formal Prrof:**

Note: A strings consists of only `a`s or consist of `b`s doesn't belongs to languagr e.g. `aa`, `a`, `bbb`...

Lets defined new Lagrange `CA`  such that `CA = {xy | Na(x) != Nb(y)}`.  `CA` stands for complement of `A`  consists of string consists of only `a`s or only `b`s.

<sup>1</sup>And CA is a regular language it's regular expression is `a+  + b+`.

Now as we know CA is a regular language (it can be expression by regular expression and so DFA) and Complement of any regular language is Regular hence language `A` is also regular language!

To construct DFA for complement language refer: [Finding the complement of a DFA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802732/finding-the-complement-of-a-dfa/14817545#14817545) and to write regular expression for DFA refer following two techniques.

1. [How to write regular expression for a DFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550711/what-is-the-language-of-this-deterministic-finite-automata/13965717#13965717)
2. [How to write regular expression for a DFA using Arden theorem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420332/need-regular-expression-for-finite-automata/17434694#17434694)

['+' Operator in Regular Expression in formal languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122755/what-will-be-the-dfa-for-the-regular-expression-00101011/14123662#14123662)

**PS:** Btw regular expression for `A = {xy | Na(x) = Nb(y)}` is `(a + b)*a(a + b)*b(a + b)*`.

Answer (score 0):

First, find out how to prove that a set is regular.
One way is to define a finite state machine that accepts the language.

Second: maybe think about why the set is not regular.

Comment: (1) First question is not about "how to proof whether a language regular"? it is about a particular problem. (2) `maybe think about why the set is not regular.` wrong to proof that certain language is not regular we have pumping lemma property of regular langue  but proofing a language is regular is quite confusing because it is necessary but not sufficient condition.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A = {a, b}*.

Try proving it by induction on length of word, or by finding the shortest word *not* in A.