# Are those two regular languages the same?

Tags: regular-language, dfa

Given an alphabet of `{a, b}` where `Na` denotes the number of occurrences of `a`, and `Nb` the number of occurrences of `b`:

> 1. `L1 = {xy | Na(x) = Nb(y)}`
> 2. `L2 = {w | Na(w) and Nb(w) are even number}`

Wouldn't a single DFA with four states and using mod be able to accept both languages?

Comment: @n.m. No, L1 **is** a [regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947420/show-that-the-following-set-over-a-b-is-regular/19065045#19065045) But yes both languages are **not** equal.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan indeed, my mistake.

Comment: @n.m. Actually it is confusing, at first it is hard to proof that it is a regular language. I also confused that it is kind of `a^nb^n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, because both languages are different so you can't draw single DFA for both languages.

An automaton uniquely defined a language, but yes of-course for a language more than one automata are possible called 'equivalent automata'.

Language  `L1 = A = {xy | Na(x) = Nb(y)}` is a regular language. Regular expression for this language is:

```
(a + b)*a(a + b)*b(a + b)*  +  ^
```

To understand this language and regular expression read: ["Show that the following set over `{a, b}` is regular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947420/show-that-the-following-set-over-a-b-is-regular).

Language  `L2 = A = {w | Na(w) and Nb(w) are even number}` is also a regular language. Regular expression for this language is:

```
((a + b(aa)*ab)(bb)*(ba(aa)*ab(bb)*)*a + (b + a(bb)*ba)(aa)*(ab(bb)*ba(aa)*)*b)*
```

To understand this language and regular expression read: ["Need Regular Expression for Finite Automata"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17434694/1673391).

But both languages are not equal because there are some strings in language L1 those are not belongs to language L2 e.g. `ab` is a string in L1 but doesn't not consist of even number of `a` and `b` hence doesn't belongs to language L2.

Note: Language L2  is either not a subset of language L1, because in  L2 a strings of even length and single symbol is possible like `aa`, `aaaa`, `bb`, `bbbb` but these strings are  not member in L1.

Both languages are different hence single DFA  is **not** possible for both languages.

Comment: The RE for L1 is just `(a+b)*`.

Comment: @n.m. To include `^` RE should be `(a + b)*a(a + b)*b(a + b)*  + ^`, but no `(a + b)*` generates = `aaaa..` or `bbb..` so not a RE for L1.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your argument. Is ^ in the language? Does x* generate ^? Does your RE generate ^?

Comment: @n.m. `^` (is nul) yes `^` string can be included in language `L1` where both prefix string `x` and suffix string `y` are `^` and constant `numberOf(a) == numberOf(b) == 0`. But a string consists of only symbol `a` or symbol `b` can't be broken into `x`, `y` such that `numberOf(a) == numberOf(b)` because at-lest  one will be zero other non-zero. No my RE in answer doesn't generate `^`.

Comment: "But a string consists of only symbol a or symbol b can't be broken into x, y" - why, of course it can, s=s^=^s, one of them will fit.

Comment: @n.m. Yes that is the reason that I said `(a + b)*` is not the RE for `L1` (what you commented). In my RE I always add at-least one `a` and one `b`...

Answer (score 0):

Both the languages L1 = {xy | Na(x) = Nb(y)} and
L2 = {w | Na(w) and Nb(w) are even number}are different so we cannot draw a single DFA for both languages.
For Language L1 :
A = {xy | Na(x) = Nb(y)} is a regular language.
Regular expression for this language is:

(a + b)*a(a + b)*b(a + b)*
Language L2 :
A = {w | Na(w) and Nb(w) are even number} is also a regular language. Regular expression for this language is:

((a + b(aa)*ab)(bb)*(ba(aa)*ab(bb)*)*a + (b + a(bb)*ba)(aa)*(ab(bb)*ba(aa)*)*b)*
Both languages are not equal because there are some strings in language L1 which doesnt belong to language L2.  ab is a string in L1 but doesn't not consist of even number of a and b hence doesn't belongs to language L2.

As Both languages are different,single DFA cannot be constructed that accepts both the languages.