# What is a complement and how to draw the graph

Tags: automation, build-automation, dfa

I don't know where to ask the question, here or in th[e mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) section or in [theoretical cs](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/). I've seen questions about this topic, here and there.

I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802732/finding-the-complement-of-a-dfa), but it's too advanced for me, we haven't learned what regex is, so i can't understand that question.

I'm asking a simple question, what is a complement? the teacher told us about it, i forgot to be honest, and the diagrams in my book are not clear.

for example:

```
Let the Alphabet {0,1}. 
L1 = { w | w ends with 0}.
L2 = { w | w contains a positive even number of 0}.
Precise the complementary of L3, then give a DFA which accept it.
```

that was my homework, just give me any example and i'll solve that one on my own, if you can just draw the graph of L1 and L2 and show me where is the complement, it will be great, that's how i understood what union is, the graph makes it easy.

And by the way, the teacher prefers that we submit the homework online, is there any way to draw DFAs? any software or web app? i don't want to use paint

Comment: [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory))

Comment: @Fischer The answer you linked in your question is answered by me..*Complement of a language L means all string those are not in L but made of same symbols*. I can answer to your question *elaborately* but you made a mistake in your question. What is `L3` in `Precise the complementary of L3, then give a DFA which accept it.` **?**, AND the tool I use to make DFA diagram is [**Dia**](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) Very good it you make report in Latex...BTW What part of answer in unclear. Give some time to understand I believe I answered from root.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan thanks so much sir!! i saw the teacher today and i asked him everything that i wanted to, everything is clear now, my exam is on monday, i understand everything and you answered many questions related to automata, i will study these answers sir, thanks so much, and the tool you offered is wonderful !!

Comment: @Fischer That is good!..N good Luck for exams..