# Cnnverting FSM to regular expression

Tags: regular-language, fsm

I know how to convert regular expression into FSM but not exactly sure how to reverse it.

[image]

what would the regular expression for this example be?

Comment: Read my this answer [Regular Expression to DFA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770814/drawing-minmal-dfa-for-the-given-regular-expression/14024179#14024179) and [to write regular expression for a DFA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550711/what-is-the-language-of-this-deterministic-finite-automata/13965717#13965717)

Comment: thank you will give it a read

Comment: um.. but the number of a has to be even for it to get to final state right? how would you represent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression for your DFA   will is  `(b + ab*a)*`

**The language description**: Symbol **`b`** can appear in any fashion but restriction is **`a`** can  to be for even number of times in language strings.

```
(b + ab*a)*
   ^   ^  ^
   |   |  "* because loop on initial state"  
   |   | "* on b because of self loop with label b on 2nd state"
   |
   |"+ because two outgoing edges, One is self loop other via 2nd state"


Here: + means Union, * means repetition for zero or more times
```

Note: Language string examples: `{^, b, aa, bababb...}`

(even `a`s and any `b`s including null)

Comment: is there a formula to do this?

Comment: @user2316675 nop, although there is a formal way to convert a FSM into RE if its in standard from -- technique is known [Arden's Therm](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=fodwUrSC8e0C&pg=SA3-PA7&lpg=SA3-PA7&dq=arden%27s%20theorem%20for%20regular%20language&source=bl&ots=QTuxWbiATB&sig=Rf32daVHvstUV5JyExianv6A4Pw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sSkZUb-9E8iUrgejlIEw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=arden%27s%20theorem%20for%20regular%20language&f=false).  But I prefer analytically way as I explained in my answer I linked with your question.

Comment: yea I was thinking just removing it one by one. but I am scared i get to exam with really complicated fsm and get stuck

Comment: @user2316675 thought my profile you can go to some answer on theory of computation. If you feels TOC is hard and mathematical [Peter Linz](http://vcetbundi.org/downloads/An%20Introduction%20to%20Formal%20Languages%20and%20Automata.pdf) is the book I suggests to students. Gook Luck for your exam!

Comment: @user2316675 ok I add a very short explanation here too.